# Sequel: Why isn't the save method saving?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I must be missing something super simple here.  In the rspec code below, the second assertion is failing, the one where the code should have been set to true:

```
  describe "#redeem!" do

    it "marks a code as redeemed" do
      existing_code = LotteryCode[promo_code: "A5"]
      existing_code.is_redeemed.should == false
      existing_code.redeem!
      changed_code = LotteryCode[promo_code: "A5"]
      changed_code.is_redeemed.should == true
    end
  end
```

Here is the model code:

```
require 'sequel'

class LotteryCode < Sequel::Model

  many_to_one :campus

  def redeem!
    is_redeemed = true
    save
  end

end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `self.is_redeemed = true`, your current code just creates a local variable.